bitrix fileInput
Я пишу проект, в котором использую bitrix. Фрагмент коды выглядит следующим образом:
<div class="form-field-container">
    <p class="status-label"><?= $formItem['label'] ?></p>
    <?
        $inputData = CFile::GetPath($arResult["ACHIVMENT"][$_GET["ID"]]["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]);
        echo \Bitrix\Main\UI\FileInput::createInstance(array(
            'name' => $formItem['name'],
            'description' => false,
            'upload' => true,
            'allowUpload' => true,
            'medialib' => true,
            'fileDialog' => true,
            'cloud' => true,
            'delete' => true,
            'maxCount' => 1,
            'accept'=>'.pdf'
        ))->show($inputData);
    ?>
</div>

Это компонент input для загрузки файлов. Проблема в том, что я хочу сделать так, чтобы единственным допустимым форматом файлов был pdf. Я пробовал сделать это следующим образом:
'accept'=>'.pdf'

но такой способ мне не помог. Как можно задать список допустимых форматов в bitrix?

А если '*.pdf'? И параметр судя по доке allowUploadExt а не какой-то accept.


Нужно указать, что будут загружаться файлы с указанными расширениями.
Нужно задать список расширений.

'allowUpload' => 'F',
'allowUploadExt' => 'pdf',

